# Error with the connection and install mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

*I would like to install and connect to mysql2 from the command line my OS is Ubuntu, I added user to have full permission but I still receive the following message:*
*ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/CHANGELOG.md*

```
:~/Desktop/simple_cms$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.9'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:76: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9/ext/mysql2
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170903-6674-101jhbn.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for rb_big_cmp()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
-----
mysql client is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.3
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.9/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/mysql2-0.4.9/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Maybe (just guessing) you created the user for 'localhost' but are connecting to 127.0.0.1... If you want a good answer i'm afraid you should provide info on how you created / granted your mysql user and an extract of your code.

Comment: localhost is 127.0.0.1 and this has nothing to do with a user as this is an IP address.

Comment: You user has no access to those files.

Comment: Make sure that when connected as this user you can access this folder and the files it contains.

Comment: I am adding you the response from the command line

Comment: I installed this: mysql client is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.
-----

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mac and installed mysql via homebrew try this:

`brew link mysql`

after that try installing the gem again:

`gem install mysql2`

Comment: fwiw I had multiple versions of mysql installed `mysql@5.5`, `mysql@5.7` and one other.  I had to execute `brew link mysql@5.5 --force`.  Be sure to check your `mysql --version` and link to the correct version.